# Having trouble with assigning custom classes in the .sks editor

Tags: sprite-kit, xcode7

I'm having trouble with setting up custom classes in the .sks editor in Xcode.  (I'm using Xcode 7.1)

I'm working on a suite of SpriteKit-based applications that will use several scenes with custom classes for the SKScene and various SKNodes.

Now, I had a proof-of-concept working.  I could create a new .sks file, go in and type in the name of my custom subclass in the "Custom Class" field of the inspector for the given scene or node, *leave the module name blank*, and it would compile properly.  It would work fine, connecting the custom subclass to the item as expected.  The workflow felt straightforward and predictable.

But then I did...*something*...and it is no longer working.  I am not sure what prompted the change, but I suspect it has something to do with trying to create another target in the same project (since I wanted to have two apps that use the same engine and just different assets and .sks files).

Anyway, now, when I compile and run my app, when I load up the .sks file, it loads without errors, but the custom subclasses are simply not applied.  No errors, no crashes, not even a notice to the console that it couldn't find the custom subclass.  Inspecting the item makes it clear that it's just a vanilla SKScene or SKSpriteNode, not the subclassed one.

I figured it had something to do with not having the correct module name any more, but I wasn't sure how to go about finding what that should be.  I tried converting the project name to letters-and-underscores, and that seemed to work for one or two things, but not reliably, which was weird.  Besides, having to type that long module name in every item was going to be a chore and error-prone - I would be typing that module name *a lot*.  I was hoping to return to the situation I was in before where I could just leave it blank.

Rolling things back, I decided, instead of adding a new target, I'd just create a different project.  I created a new project, moved the assets over, and tried to instantiate them, and again, it didn't work!  Now, I can't get them to recognize anything, regardless of what I put in the module field.

I'm guessing the .sks files are somehow "baking" the current module into the file or something?  But I can't seem to wrangle them into submission.

What I'd *like* to be able to do is just create my .sks files for a project, enter the name of the subclass I want it to use - regardless of module - and keep everything in the same "default module" so that I can use my shared codebase for the engine or my custom subclasses for that target.  The workflow I had originally was great, but I can't seem to achieve that for anything other than one target.

Is that unrealistic?  Are there some best practices or other techniques to getting those .sks files to reliably load the subclasses I want them to load?

*Edit:* As requested, here's how I'm loading the scene (some variable names changed to add clarity for this example):

```
if let start = SKScene(fileNamed: "Scene0") {
        start.scaleMode = .AspectFill
        spriteKitSceneView!.presentScene( start )
        if let _ = start as? CustomScene {
            print("Scene0 is a CustomScene")
        } else {
            print("Scene0 is NOT a CustomScene")
        }
    } else {
        print("Could not get Scene0")
    }
 }
```

The print statements are there to clarify what happens.  This code would print out "Scene0 is NOT a CustomScene", even though I've typed in "CustomScene" as the custom class for the scene in the .sks editor.

Comment: did you check to make sure you didn't delete the class from the custom class you are inheriting from?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I didn't.  I put in some test code to check for the scene being the custom class, and it didn't throw any errors when I referenced that class.  I have all that code set with the correct targets, and it all compiles without errors.  It just doesn't seem to apply the custom classes...

Comment: pretty sure?  you could just check to verify, then we could move on to the next step of deleting from interface builder, and checking if the auto complete finds it.

Comment: Well, I say "pretty sure" because I'm not understanding what happened to make the .sks files no longer able to recognize those custom classes.  They're available at compile-time - I can reference them in code without it throwing errors - but they are not available at runtime, apparently, at least for the purpose of loading .sks files.  (Also, note that this is using the SpriteKit scene editor, not interface builder.  It doesn't do autocomplete, so that path of investigation is kind of a dead end...)

Comment: class CustomClass : Class  <-----does it look like that

Comment: You mean in the code?  Yes.  For instance, I have "public class MyScene : SKScene" as the declarator for a custom scene.  I then put "MyScene" in the "Custom Class" field in the .sks editor, but it creates that scene as a standard, vanilla SKScene instead of a MyScene.  It doesn't even show a warning or anything - it just seems to ignore that field.

Comment: can you post how you are loading your sks file

Comment: I've edited the post to include the code I'm using to load the .sks file.

Answer (score 1):

When you are trying to create your object, you are creating it with the wrong initializer.  You want to use `if let start = CustomScene(fileNamed: "Scene0")`  Otherwise you are saying that start should be a SKScene,  which is not what you want.

Comment: Well, that code worked when creating custom subclasses of SKScene before, so I'm fairly certain you don't need to specify the custom subclass when asking it to decode an .sks file.  Also, I don't know the custom subclass of SKScene that will be loaded at author-time; that's defined in the .sks file.  That code could be loading up many different .sks files, all with different custom subclasses.  Besides, that wouldn't explain why custom subclasses of, say, SKSpriteNodes and SKNodes *within* the .sks file also fail to attach to their custom classes.  Something else is the issue, I'm pretty sure.

Comment: It may have been a bug that got fixed then , but that is the reason you  are not getting a custom class,  calling SKScene() should not be creating any other object other than  an SKScene.  I will edit my answer to show you what you should be doing

Comment: Looks like this is an issue with iOS 8,  I changed it to iOS 9, and everything works with the custom class, I was going to edit my code, but I am doing something completely different then what you are doing,  I know the custom class to be called, so  I am forcing the call